# R sort() ignores locale on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: r, ubuntu

I ran the following code in R, version 3.6.0, on Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 18.04:

```
Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_COLLATE")
sid = c("MEL058", "NE-ICU011", "NE-ICU012", "NE-ICU014", "NE023", "NE035")
print(sort(sid))
```

On Ubuntu 16.04, I get:

```
[1] "en_US.UTF-8"
[1] "MEL058"    "NE023"     "NE035"     "NE-ICU011" "NE-ICU012" "NE-ICU014"
```

On Ubuntu 18.04, I get:

```
[1] "en_US.UTF-8"
[1] "MEL058"    "NE-ICU011" "NE-ICU012" "NE-ICU014" "NE023"     "NE035"
```

As can be seen, locale is the same on both platforms. sessionInfo() is also identical, but the results are different. What is the explanation?

Comment: What does `icuGetCollate()` say?

Comment: 16.04: "ICU not in use"  18.04: "root"

Comment: There you have it. Try changing the ICU locale to `"en_US"`.

Comment: Thanks. Tried it, got "ICU is not supported on this build". But `Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_COLLATE", locale = "C")` yields consistent sort results across OS versions

Comment: I wonder if icuGetCollate() status should be part of sessionInfo(). It affects sorting of strings, and is currently invisible unless you explicitly call it. I suspect not too many R users are aware of ICU and impact on sorting

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question based in part on comments by @Roland:

R can optionally be built to use the ICU Unicode library
http://site.icu-project.org/home. The presence of ICU affects sort()
results on strings.

Apparently, R 3.6.0 build on Ubuntu 16.04 does not include ICU support; the
build on 18.04 does. This explains why sort() function on strings
gives different results on the two platforms.

To find out if your R build uses ICU, type (example given for Ubuntu
16.04, R 3.6.0 build):

```
> icuGetCollate()
[1] "ICU not in use"
```

If you want to use ASCII collating sequence, issue this command

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_COLLATE", locale = "C")
```

before sort(). This will yield identical results across operating systems.

Ideally, sessionInfo() should say whether R uses ICU or not. Right
now, this information is essentially hidden from users unaware of
icuGetCollate().